# React - Refactor out eval function and improve code quality

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just started playing with React today and built a simple Calculator app. 
Would someone please be able to advise on steps I could take to improve my code.

Ideally, I want ideas on how to properly use state, and how to refactor out my use of the eval function.

Would appreciate any feedback on how you would have done this differently aswell :)

```js
import React from 'react';

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        prev: [],
        total: []
      };
  }

  inputDigit(int) {

    var newArr = this.state.total.slice();
    newArr.push(int);
    this.setState({total: newArr});

  }

  addition(prevNum) {

    var store = this.arrToNum(prevNum);
    var newArr = this.state.prev.slice();
    newArr.push(store , "+");
    var string = newArr.join(" ");
    this.setState({total:[] , prev: [string]});

    return prevNum;

  }

  minus(prevNum) {

    var store = this.arrToNum(prevNum);
    var newArr = this.state.prev.slice();
    newArr.push(store , "-");
    var string = newArr.join(" ");
    this.setState({total:[] , prev: [string]});

    return prevNum;

  }

  divide(prevNum) {

    var store = this.arrToNum(prevNum);
    var newArr = this.state.prev.slice();
    newArr.push(store , "/");
    var string = newArr.join(" ");
    this.setState({total:[] , prev: [string]});

    return prevNum;

  }

  multiply(prevNum) {

    var store = this.arrToNum(prevNum);
    var newArr = this.state.prev.slice();
    newArr.push(store , "*");
    var string = newArr.join(" ");
    this.setState({total:[] , prev: [string]});

    return prevNum;
  }

  clearInput() {

    this.setState({total:[],prev:[]});

  }

  sum(currNum) {

    var store = this.arrToNum(currNum);
    var newArr = this.state.prev.slice();
    newArr.push(store);
    console.log(newArr.join(" "));
    var sum = eval(newArr.join(" "));

    this.setState({total:[sum]});

  }

  arrToNum(arr) {

    var test = Number(arr.join(''));

    return test;

  }

  makePretty(num) {

    var newNum = this.arrToNum(num);
    var formatNum = newNum.toLocaleString();

    return formatNum;

  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="Calculator">
        <div className="Screen">
          <p>{this.makePretty(this.state.total)}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="KeyPad">
          <div className="row">
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(7)}>7</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(8)}>8</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(9)}>9</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.addition(this.state.total)}>+</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(4)}>4</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(5)}>5</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(6)}>6</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.minus(this.state.total)}>-</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(1)}>1</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(2)}>2</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(3)}>3</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.multiply(this.state.total)}>*</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(0)}>0</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(".")}>.</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.sum(this.state.total)}>=</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.divide(this.state.total)}>/</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="square full" onClick={() => this.clearInput()}>CLEAR</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calculator;
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [codereview.se]

Comment: Thankyou @TomFenech, I will post it there.

Answer (score 2):

1-

```
inputDigit(int) {
  this.setState({total: [
    ...this.state.total,
    int
  ]})
}
```

2-

```
addition(prevNum) {
 let store = this.arrToNum(prevNum);
 let string = [...this.state.prev, store, '+'].join(' ');
 this.setState({total:[] , prev: [string]});
 return prevNum;
}
```

and you have to follow the same pattern for the rest of the functions

3- add this function

```
renderItem(value, onClick) {
   return <button className="square" onClick={onclick}>{value}</button> 
}
```

4- replace this:

```
<div className="row">
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(7)}>7</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(8)}>8</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.inputDigit(9)}>9</button>
            <button className="square" onClick={() => this.addition(this.state.total)}>+</button>
          </div>
```

with this

```
<div className="row">
  {[
     ['7',() => this.inputDigit(7)],
     ['8',() => this.inputDigit(8)],
     ['9',() => this.inputDigit(9)],
     ['+',() => this.addition(this.state.total)],
   ].map(([value, onClick]) => this.renderItem(value, onClick)})
```

5- follow the same pattern with all the views

Answer (score 0):

And that's another code review...

```
import React from 'react'

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  state = {
    prev: [],
    total: []
  }

  inputDigit(int) {
    let {state} = this.state
    this.setState({
      total: [...total, int]
    })
  }

  action(prevNum, symbol) {
    let store = Number(prevNum.join(''))
    let {prev} = this.state
    let string = [...prev, store, symbol].join(' ')
    this.setState({total: [], prev: [str]})
    return prevNum
  }

  clearInput() {
    this.setState({total: [], prev: []})
  }

  sum(currNum) {
    let store = Number(currNum.join(''))
    let {prev} = this.state
    let sum = eval([...prev, store].join(' '))
    this.setState({total: [sum]})
  }

  makePretty(num) {
    return Number(num.join('')).toLocaleString()
  }
  renderItem(value, onClick) {
    if (!onClick) onClick = () => this.inputDigit(value)
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={onclick}>
        {value}
      </button>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Calculator">
        <div className="Screen">
          <p>{this.makePretty(this.state.total)}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="KeyPad">
          <div className="row">
            {[
              [7],
              [8],
              [9],
              ['+', () => this.action(this.state.total, '+')]
            ].map(([value, _function]) => this.renderItem(value, _function))}
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            {[
              [4],
              [5],
              [6],
              ['-', () => this.action(this.state.total, '-')]
            ].map(([value, _function]) => this.renderItem(value, _function))}
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            {[
              [1],
              [2],
              [3],
              ['*', () => this.action(this.state.total, '*')]
            ].map(([value, _function]) => this.renderItem(value, _function))}
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            {[
              [0],
              ['.'],
              ['='],
              ['/', () => this.action(this.state.total, '/')]
            ].map(([value, _function]) => this.renderItem(value, _function))}
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button className="square full" onClick={() => this.clearInput()}>
              CLEAR
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```